# I have imported the searchBox component into the App component. which is showing this error, 'searchBox' is defined but never used '

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import CardList from './components/CardList';
import searchBox from './components/searchBox';
import { robots } from './components/robots';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <searchBox/>
      <CardList robots = {robots}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was supposed to see the searchBox on the main page but it is showing the error even though I am using this component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [react.dev docs](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#step-2-define-the-function)

> React components are regular JavaScript functions, but their names must start with a capital letter or they won’t work!

You'll have to import your searchBox like so

```js
import SearchBox from "./components/searchBox";
```

And use it like this

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>RoboFriends</h1>
      <SearchBox />
      <CardList robots={robots} />
    </>
  );
}
```